Using the Trilogy Adapter with a Rails application causes an error
I generated a new Rails 7.1 application, and made sure the Mysql gem was removed from the Gemfile. I did not include the Trilogy gem, as the docs said that the Trilogy adapter is included in Rails 7.1
Then I did:
rails generate model Book name:string email:string 

And the response was:
/Users/joseph-mac/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': 
Error loading the 'trilogy' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? 
trilogy is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile. (LoadError)
from /Users/joseph-mac/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.3.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/trilogy_adapter.rb:5:in `<main>'

My database.yml file:
default: &default
  adapter: trilogy
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock


The trilogy ADAPTER is part of rails/activerecord -- you still need the gem.

I added the mysql gem, but I'm still getting the same error

Add the trilogy gem -- from the log you provided -> trilogy is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.

From the Trilogy GitHub repo: ⚠️ Rails v7.1+ includes Trilogy support by default making this gem unnecessary. I added an issue to the GitHub repo

That's the adapter gem https://github.com/trilogy-libraries/activerecord-trilogy-adapter -- you still need the client. Nowhere in the trilogy gem repo does it say it is not required. https://github.com/trilogy-libraries/trilogy
